# Form not showing in ie7

Tags: php, css

I have a form in the nave bar of my site that is visible in all browsers except ie7 (and of course ie6). When I view it through Adobe Browse labs, for ie7, it seems that it recognizes the space of form, but doesn't show it.

savingsulove dot com

I have been troubleshooting this problem for hours and can't figure it out. I would appreciate some help on this. Thanks a mil.

Comment: Could you post some relevant code?

Comment: I'd start with correcting the errors: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.savingsulove.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: What exactly do you need? a vague question, be more specific.!

Comment: @TJHeuvel: sorry for not including the code, but someone pointed out the problem to me. It was a negative margin that I forgot that I targeted for ie7.

Comment: @RoToRa: Thanks, I'll do a thorough validation.

Comment: @Fernando: What I needed what was to get the form displayed in ie 7. But thanks the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some huge negative margin applied to the form in IE7:

```
#searchBox {*margin-left: -650px;}
```

(second "styles.css")

Tip of the day: install the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535) in IE7 or use the embedded one in IE8 (F12 to call it) then switch to IE7 standards. Inspect the form. See the margin error and locate the right CSS file. Remove this declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I forgot I targeted ie7, oops. I will definitely use the ie dev toolbar. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I had to thank you again. The ie dev toolbar is REALLY useful. I always wondered if internet explorer had one. I always stuck with firefox because their firebug develop toolbar is very user friendly. Thanks again!